# Is it there any way to delay the creation of every thread on openmp?

Tags: c, openmp

I was trying to parallelize a code to get the first "n" prime numbers with openmp but i realised i get the same numbers repeated. I tried to make the variable private but the problem is that every thread starts on the same number so I don't know if ist any way to delay a thread so every thread starts on a different number. Here is the code I managed to do:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <omp.h>


    void qs(int lista[],int limite_izq,int limite_der)
    {
        int izq,der,temporal,pivote;

        izq=limite_izq;
        der = limite_der;
        pivote = lista[(izq+der)/2];

        do{
            while(lista[izq]<pivote && izq<limite_der)izq++;
            while(pivote<lista[der] && der > limite_izq)der--;
            if(izq <=der)
            {
                temporal= lista[izq];
                lista[izq]=lista[der];
                lista[der]=temporal;
                izq++;
                der--;
            }
        }while(izq<=der);
        if(limite_izq<der){qs(lista,limite_izq,der);}
        if(limite_der>izq){qs(lista,izq,limite_der);}
    }

    void quicksort(int lista[],int n)
    {
        qs(lista,0,n-1);
    }


    int main() {
        int n_total_primes = 10, n = n_total_primes;
        int i=3;
        int aux = 0;
        int vector[n_total_primes];

        double t1 = omp_get_wtime();


        omp_set_num_threads(4);
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (n = 1; n < n_total_primes; n++) {
            for (aux = 2; aux < i; aux++) {
                if (i % aux == 0) {
                    aux = i;
                }
            }

            if (i == aux) {
                vector[n] = i;
                n++;
            }
            i++;
            n--;
        }

        vector[0] = 2;
        double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
        printf("Total time: %lf\n", t2-t1);

        quicksort(vector,n_total_primes);

        for ( i = 0 ; i < n_total_primes ; i++ )
            printf("%d\n",vector[i]);

        printf("\nnum_primes=%d, last prime: %d\n", n_total_primes, vector[n_total_primes-1]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: We cannot help you fix incomplete code, please create a [mcve]. Be **specific** about what you *tried*.

Comment: I think what you'll want to do is have each thread start with a different `n`, such that `n = 1 + <thread_number>`, and then increment by the number of threads rather than by 1.  So with 4 threads, then `thread 0` will work on `n=1`, `n=5`, `n=9`, etc., `thread 1` will work on `n=2`, `n=6`, `n=10`, etc..

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't a complete program, but the parallelization happens automatically--each thread will start at a different `n`. Having said that, it looks like you have all manner of shared variables, so I don't see how multiple threads accessing those with an arbitrary interleaving is going to do much good.

Comment: I completed the program, my problem is that the different threads try with the same prime number so i get the same prime number many times. It's not about optimizee the code, I just want it to work and then i'll care about how to make it better. Thanks you all.

Comment: Listen to @ggorlen, and think about the scope of many of your variables. Did you really want to be sharing aux and i, and what happens to n if multiple threads are changing it at the same time? It is good C/C++ practice to declare variables in the minimal scope, and that *really* helps when parallelising with OpenMP...

Comment: I see it's not worth it to share all those variables, but at first I just want it to work, then I'll focus on changing variables so I can optimize it. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me make it work because I'm still blocked.